# How to zip files in a loop and move them to different directories?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I want to zip the files based on the file names which are dynamic.
I have file called : ClientNames

```
CODE, Client Name
1111, ABC
1231, XYZ
1211, APT
1561, OPT
```

My file name is : MAA.TRD.1111.2016.20.09.csv    (*FILENAME.CODE.YEAR.DATE.MONTH*.csv)
I have multiple files with different CODES in a directory.

Everytime I need to check the CODE, fetch its Client Name from ClientNames file and zip the file with name - 
(for filename: MAA.TRD.1111.2016.20.09.csv zip file name : ABC.20162009.csv; MAA.TRD.1211.2016.20.09.csv zip file name should be : APT.20162009.csv and likewise )

I want to design a loop where it will take one by one file in and zip it, rename it.

My code is:

```
FILES=MAA.TRD*.csv

for file in ${FILES}
    do
    ls -lrt MAA.TRD*.csv | cut -d '.' -f 3 > $SCRIPT/LogfileCODE
    cd $SCRIPT
    DATE=`date`
    Filename=`grep -Fwf $LogfileCODE $ClientNames | cut -d ',' -f 2`
    ZIPFILENAME="${Filename}_${DATE}"         
    echo " Zipping of file is starting "
    zip -j ${ZIPFILENAME}-$DATE.zip $file           
done
```

But my for loop is taking all the files together. Please help.

Comment: maybe you want to use $file in your `ls -lr` instead of repeating the wildcard/glob?

Comment: I want to capture just a CODE (1111) in the LogfileCODE so I am doing ls -lr & then cut.

Comment: you goal is not completely clear.  are you trying to zip one or possibly more files containing a CODE in the filename into a zip file with a name you set based on the CODE in the original filenames?  or are you just renaming files (i.e. one at a time) and zipping the renamed file?

Comment: I am sorry if my questions isn't clear. Please check again, I have updated.

Comment: I am trying to rename the file with the respective ClientNames & then trying to zip it.

Comment: look at comment from @jeff.  he has already said where the main problem lies in your script.  you are looping on a list of the files you have in some directory, then you redundantly list those files out again in the loop for every file in your directory.

Comment: How can I fix it? I want to rename the files and zip it in a loop. I would really appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1  DATE=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
2
3  for FILE in MAA.TRD*.csv
4  do
5      CODE=$(echo $FILE | cut -d. -f3)
6      CLIENT=$(grep -w $CODE ClientNames | sed 's/^.*, //')
7      NEWFILE=$CLIENT.$DATE.csv
8      mv $FILE $NEWFILE
9      echo " Zipping of $NEWFILE is starting "
10     zip -j $NEWFILE.zip $NEWFILE           
11 done
```

1  - set the date, best to use a format like this that won't have spaces in it, feel free to adjust to your preference

3  - just loop on the glob of files you have in the directory (this will expand to all files matching the naming convention you outline)

5  - get the CODE from the filename

6  - get the CLIENT from ClientNames based on the CODE of the current file (using sed here to include stripping the space after the comma, if there is not actually a space `cut -d, -f2` will work instead) - this assumes ClientNames is in the CWD, use a full path if necessary

7  - build the new filename for easy reuse later

8  - rename the file to your new name

10 - zip the file (you don't want a zipfile ending in .csv)

Comment: this is creating just one zip file but I want to create zip file for each NEWFILE

Comment: did you try this code, and you are only getting one zip file?  the loop acts individually on every file matching MAA.TRD*.csv in your directory, so you should end up with a new zip file for each different file it finds.